# change Datetime format django rest framework

Tags: model, django-rest-framework

I want to change date time format in django rest framework

I have implement one logic but it's not fullfill my requirement

Model

```
class User (models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

setting.py file I have define the datetime format

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
}
```

Query

```
data = User.objects.filter(pk=51)
serializer = UserSerializer(data, many=True)
```

result after serializer data

```
 {
      "user_id": 41406,
      "user_name": "abc@gmail.com",
      "created_at": "09/26/2016 22:52:16",
 }
```

Now when I hit another model then datetime format is also same like this "09/26/2016 22:52:16" but i do not want this date format in anthor model.

Please let me know if we can change in particular Model datetime format and call it in serializer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can override `to_representation` method in a model serializer which required different date output:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['created_at'] = instance.created_at.strftime(<your format string>)
        return representation
```

Or you can write custom field and use it instead of default.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y')
    # add read_only=True to the field in case if date created automatically
    ...
```

Comment: @thumbtackthief it is just a string to replace with format you want. I'll make it a comment for clarity

Comment: Format string can be something like format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"

Answer (score 4):

@dc_Bita98 already gave the correct solution.

But for someone who wants to convert the month number to the month name, try this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%B %d, %Y', # returns November 8, 2021
    ... 
}
```

or this for the abbreviation of the month name:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%b %d, %Y', # returns Nov 8, 2021
    ... 
}
```

**Note**: I'm using Django REST Framework version 3.12.4

Answer (score 4):

To provide more granular option, you can use SerializerMethodField:

```
class User (models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_created_at(self, obj):
        return obj.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

And this format will only apply to this specific serializer attribute.

You can use this to any of your field with the format `get_<field_name>`. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

Comment: This is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, in **settings.py**:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ["%d-%m-%Y", ],
    ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this isn't an answer yet but in the serializer....

```
date = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
```